# JndiException: Error parsing JNDI name in Standalone Application

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, h2

I am trying to use hibernate and a h2 database in a standalone application without any application server.

Also, i can connect to the h2 database (using file mode for testing) via some database tool.

I've set up my project as a maven project, include following dependencies:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.199</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    <version>5.4.4.Final</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>5.4.4.Final</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.9.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

persistence.xml  (resources/META-INF/persistence.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" version="2.0">

    <persistence-unit name="sow-quest-unit">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <!--        <provider>org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl</provider>-->
        <!--        <jta-data-source>jdbc:h2:file:D:\Projects\SecretWoods\db</jta-data-source>-->

        <non-jta-data-source>jdbc:h2:file:D:\Projects\SecretWoods\db</non-jta-data-source>

        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:h2:file:D:\Projects\SecretWoods\db" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:h2:file:D:\Projects\SecretWoods\db" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="org.h2.Driver" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="admin" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="admin" />
            <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class" />
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hbm2ddl.auto" value="create" />
            <property name="transaction-type" value="RESOURCE-LOCAL"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

hibernate.cfg.xml (resources/hibernate.cfg.xml)

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
    "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
    <property name="connection.url">jdbc:h2:file:D:\Projects\SecretWoods\db</property>
    <property name="connection.driver_class">org.h2.Driver</property>

    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:h2:file:D:\Projects\SecretWoods\db</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.h2.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">admin</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">admin</property>
    <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection">class</property>
    <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.format_sql">true</property>
    <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create</property>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect</property>
    <property name="transaction-type">RESOURCE-LOCAL</property>
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

and my code:

```
package com.wolfo.database;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;

import com.wolfo.quest.QText;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Slf4j
@Service
public class DatabaseMain {

//  @PersistenceContext(unitName = "sow-quest-unit")
//  private EntityManager entityManager;

    public void createEnitites()    {

        EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("sow-quest-unit");
        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();


        QText qText = new QText();
        qText.setText("test text");
//      entityManager.persist(qText);

    }

}
```

Error:
When trying to inject or create a entitymanager with a entitymanger factory, the exceptions are thrown:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.engine.jndi.JndiException: Error parsing JNDI name [jdbc:h2:file:D:\Projects\SecretWoods\db]
    at 
    ... 17 more
Caused by: javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:662)
```

Additional Infos:

I tried it without transaction-type=RESOURCE-LOCAL.
And i tried jta-data-source aswell non-jta-data-source...

After a debugging session the reason is:
In JndiServiceImpl (Hibernate)  there is a method

```
private Name parseName(String jndiName, Context context)
```

jndiName is filled, but Context seems to be empty:

[image: Debug Window]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that it is not possible to use EntityManager?!

I tried following now:
deleteted persitence.xml, edited hibernate.cfg.xml (added following):

```
<property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>

<property name="hibernate.dbcp.initialSize">5</property>
<property name="hibernate.dbcp.maxTotal">20</property>
<property name="hibernate.dbcp.maxIdle">10</property>
<property name="hibernate.dbcp.minIdle">5</property>
<property name="hibernate.dbcp.maxWaitMillis">-1</property>

<mapping class="com.wolfo.quest.Quest" />
<mapping class="com.wolfo.quest.QAnswer" />
<mapping class="com.wolfo.quest.QQuestion" />
<mapping class="com.wolfo.quest.QText" />
```

After that i wrote some class (found in an example):

```
private static StandardServiceRegistry registry;
private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;

public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    if (sessionFactory == null) {
        try {
            // Create registry
            registry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().configure().build();

            // Create MetadataSources
            MetadataSources sources = new MetadataSources(registry);

            // Create Metadata
            Metadata metadata = sources.getMetadataBuilder().build();

            // Create SessionFactory
            sessionFactory = metadata.getSessionFactoryBuilder().build();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            if (registry != null) {
                StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.destroy(registry);
            }
        }
    }
    return sessionFactory;
}

public static void shutdown() {
    if (registry != null) {
        StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.destroy(registry);
    }
}
```

It works now, but i thought i could use the EntityManager?!